# AWS Athena returns no rows

Tags: terraform, amazon-athena

I have created athena database and table using terraform, successfully created but when i hit preview table in AWS console there are no rows showing.

My data file is in s3 bucket "s3://somefolder/subfolder/subfolder1/sampledata.csv". Using the aws wizard for creating table using s3, there are no issues. I can preview the table etc. with terraform created , there are no rows showing.

File type - csv

```
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "s3-input" {
  name = "my_employee_table_poc"
  database_name = aws_glue_catalog_database.my_db.name
  table_type = "EXTERNAL_TABLE"

  storage_descriptor {
    location = "s3://somefolder/subfolder/subfolder1"
    input_format = "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat"
    output_format = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat"

  /*  ser_de_info {
            name    = "SerDeCsv"
            serialization_library = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe"
           
    */

    ser_de_info {
    name = "my-first-serde"
    serialization_library = "org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe"
    #serialization_library = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe"
  

    parameters = {
      "serialization.format" = 1
 
     }
 }
```

Comment: `serialization_library = "org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe"` seems odd for a CSV file.

Comment: should i change it to the commented line ```#serialization_library = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe"```

Comment: Check what is the serde library that is working when you are doing it manually or through the wizard and use the same value in your Terraform script

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing out. updated the serialization with the below for csv file type and it worked.

serialization_library = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde"